# Different results if using: $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare())

Tags: wordpress, prepared-statement

Simple database structure:

[image: Database]

If I do:

```
SELECT info FROM `wp_participants_database` WHERE standard = '456' AND zertifikatsnummer = 'iso777' AND _firmennamen = 'Firma789';
```

I get: "d", which is fine.

But when im using `$wpdb`, like here:

```
$query = "SELECT info FROM wp_participants_database WHERE standard = %d AND zertifikatsnummer = %d  AND _firmennamen = %d";
    $firmennamenx = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare( $query, '456', 'iso777', 'Firma789' ));
    echo $firmennamenx->info;
```

I get: "b", why?

Comment: replace zertifikatsnummer = %s  AND _firmennamen = %s and let me know what happens

Comment: I don't know why, but it works.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
$query = "SELECT info FROM wp_participants_database WHERE standard = %d AND zertifikatsnummer = %s  AND _firmennamen = %s";
    $firmennamenx = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare( $query, '456', 'iso777', 'Firma789' ));
    echo $firmennamenx->info;
```

Here %d is for the decimal values and %s for the string value. Your other fields are having the string value so for that you need to set %s

Hope now you got my point why you need to set %s.

Comment: Now it makes sense to me. Thanks for your Answer.